# Problem in install R using conda on a server cluster

Tags: r, anaconda, conda

I tried to install R on cluster server using conda. Conda created environment successfully, but it can not install R. It gives the following error message:

```
-bash-4.2$ conda install -c conda-forge r-base=4.2.0
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): failed

# >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> ERROR REPORT <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/opt/ohpc/pub/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/conda/gateways/connection/session.py", line 52, in __call__
        return cls._thread_local.session
    AttributeError: '_thread._local' object has no attribute 'session'
     active environment : /home/zwei/bartsfm
    active env location : /home/zwei/bartsfm
            shell level : 3
       user config file : /home/zwei/.condarc
 populated config files : /home/zwei/.condarc
          conda version : 4.8.3
    conda-build version : 3.18.11
         python version : 3.8.3.final.0
       virtual packages : __glibc=2.17
       base environment : /opt/ohpc/pub/anaconda3  (read only)
           channel URLs : https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/linux-64
                          https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/linux-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/linux-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
          package cache : /home/zwei/conda/pkgs
       envs directories : /home/zwei/bartsfm
                          /home/zwei/.conda/envs
                          /opt/ohpc/pub/anaconda3/envs
               platform : linux-64
             user-agent : conda/4.8.3 requests/2.24.0 CPython/3.8.3 Linux/3.10.0-1160.76.1.el7.x86_64 Linux/unknown glibc/2.17
                UID:GID : 1620:1546
             netrc file : None
           offline mode : False

 ...

An unexpected error has occurred. Conda has prepared the above report.

Upload successful.
```

I guess I mess up the environment variables for conda. Could any one help? Many thanks.

Comment: What happens if you create a new environment directly with R? E.g., `conda create -n foo r-base=4.2`.

Comment: Also, the `conda` version here is quite old (even given the date of original post). Be sure to run `conda update -n base conda`.